# Winsock server message isn't showing on client side terminal

Tags: tcp, server, winsock, winsock2

I created a simple TCP server listening on 8080 port that sends a message to the client once a connection is established. Here's the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#pragma warning(disable:4996) 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s, new_socket;
    int c;
    int ret;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    char* message = "Thank you for connecting to us but i got to go\n";

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0) {
        printf("Failed to initialize Winsock : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }



    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Error creating socket : %d", WSAGetLastError());

    }


    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(8080);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;


    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Error binding socket : %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    listen(s, 3);

    puts("Listening for incoming connection\n");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    while (new_socket = accept(s, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &c) != INVALID_SOCKET) {
        puts("Connection established\n");
        send(new_socket, message, strlen(message), 0);
    }

    if (new_socket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Connection failed : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();


    return 0;

}
```

When I'm running this, the server runs just fine. I open another terminal and open telnet and try to connect to the server on 8080 port. This is the client side terminal.

```
Welcome to Microsoft Telnet Client

Escape Character is 'CTRL+]'

Microsoft Telnet> open localhost 8080
Connecting To localhost...
```

And this is the server side.

```
Listening for incoming connection

Connection established
```

But even after server says that a connection is established, the client side stays at "Connecting to localhost". I send the message "Thank you for connecting to us but i got to go\n" but it doesn't show on the client side. what can possibly be wrong?

Comment: Since telnet is not just a raw send / receive bytes channel, your telnet client is probably waiting for some response to the options it send while attempting to connect (the protocol is described by [RFC854](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc854). For testing purposes you are probably better off building your own client.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As it appears, it was a silly mistake.

```
while (new_socket = accept(s, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &c) != INVALID_SOCKET)
```

Since I didn't put another bracket over the new_socket = accept(s, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &c after initializing `new_socket`, the inequality was being applied on the `accept` function return.

The correct syntax would be

```
while ((new_socket = accept(s, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &c)) != INVALID_SOCKET)
```

Comment: If you had bothered to error-check your system calls, specifically `send()`, you would have found this problem for yourself immediately. Don't write code like this.